# How to set content type as text/xml in response message header using spring

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I have developed a spring webservice which will return an empty response, but the problem is content-type is going as text/palin. i want to set the content type as text/xml, have searched for options but couldn't get exact way to do it.

here is my code:

```
@Endpoint
public class Service{

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://sample.com/webservice", localPart = "sendReport")
    @ResponsePayload
    public void recieveReport(@RequestPayload SendReport report){
        // processing the report response
    }

}
```

Can some one please explin soon, as this is blocking my current work.

Comment: you can use `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring 3.1 you can do this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDealers", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
produces = "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public String sendMobileData() {

}
```

add the produces attribute & set the content type

There is one more way

you can put `response.setContentType("text/xml");` in your method

```
public String yourAction(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
}
```

Comment: I tried the first option but no luck. but with the second option i am not sending any response then how can i set content type in response.

Comment: You stated in your question " but the problem is content-type is going as text/palin. i want to set the content type as text/xml". I told you how to set the content type

Comment: we found that WAS server is actually replacing the content type as text/palin in the response xml, because  MIME type is set to text/plain in server configuration file.